# JSON HTML File Link

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file and a html file. When I try to link them like `<link rel="contents" type="application/json" href="users2.json" />` it doesn't work or I can't access the file like `user1.name`.

Comment: When you say "link them", what are you trying to accomplish? A clickable link?

Comment: I am trying to GET and POST data to and fro the data file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rel="import"` at `<link>` element to import the file into the document. You can then use `.import` property of `<link>` element to get the contents of the linked file.

Comment: can you show a complete example? thanks in advance.

Comment: But it seems that this approach is no longer supported by modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a json file like:

`var user = {
  name: 'Your Name'
}`

and import script
`<script src="user.json"></script>`

Comment: I get `Attribute "scr" not allowed on element "script" at this point.`

Comment: @ds_secret the attribute name is not **scr** but **src**